# Permutations in python DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, python-3.8

I have a list,

```
lst= ['A','R','N','C','D','Q','E','G','H','I','L','K','M','F','P','S','T','W','Y','V']
```

I want to create a columns to a df with the possible permutations of the above list.
I have used the below code but I get a memory error:

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0ab6c40ebc27> in <module>
      1 import itertools
----> 2 list(itertools.permutations(lst))
```

code:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.permutations(lst))
```

Is there any other way to create columns to a DataFrame from the permutated values of this list?

Comment: how many columns do you need, and what is the value of the permutations? you have to give a integer or it will continue to give you MemoryError. and can you give expected output please.

Comment: lst= ['A','R','N','C','D','Q','E','G','H','I','L','K','M','F','P','S','T','W','Y','V']
I need 20 columns of each of the above 20 letters plus permutated values of these letters with repeation=TRUE i.e 400 columns for 20 letter. In total 20+400 columns.
AR,AN,AC,AD......RA,RN,RC,,,,,NA,NR,NC...so on 400 permutated pairs

Comment: well if you whant that output: `per = it.permutations(lst, 2)` will give you `[('A', 'R'),
('A', 'N'),
 ('A', 'C'),
 ('A', 'D'),
 ('A', 'Q'),
 ('A', 'E'),
 ('A', 'G'),
 ('A', 'H'),`....], But can you explain the last logic you are refering to "plus permutated values of these letters with repeation=TRUE i.e 400 columns for 20 letter. In total 20+400 columns"

Answer (score 0):

With 20 symbols, you get 20! permutations which is about 2.4E18. You will never have enough memory to hold that many permutations. Assuming 1 byte per character, you would need 48 exabytes of storage.